# SQL inserting backslash even with string replacement

Tags: php, sql

I have an INSERT function that's working properly except when I'm trying to add a value with a quote. I have this block of code to replace the single quote with two singles and then insert it, but nothing is being changed. I changed the host and password for this example.

```
$title = str_replace("'", " '' ", $title);

  //Connecting to the database
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=workinghost;dbname=mydatabase', $username, $password);

if (!($stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO calendar(title, start) VALUES(:title, :start)"))) 
{
    //echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysql->errno . ") " . $mysql->error;
}

$stmt->bindParam(":title", $title);
$stmt->bindParam(":start", $date);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Did you actually execute the prepared statement? Your code doesn't appear to do so.

Comment: "with two singles" - you mean a double quote?

Comment: No I mean that I change the single quote to two single quotes

Comment: A `"` is called a double quote :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled. Turn them off.